# How to keep Date objects in different time zones in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Is it possible in JavaScript to keep Date objects in different time zones, e.g.:

```
date1.toString();
>>> 2012-02-16T14:00+02:00

date2.toString();
>>> 2012-03-16T13:00+01:00
```

i.e. I have two date objects they reflect the same moment of the time but keep their information in different time zones.

Comment: Internally, the dates/times are kept independent of the timezones. Timezones are only applied on output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Dates in JavaScript represent a moment in time; they do not store time zone information. You can then choose to display what time that represents in a particular timezone. *(See the various methods like `getHours()`—current local time zone—versus `getUTCHours()`.)*

To display a time in a timezone other than UTC or the local you need to write (or use) a function that does a bit of math:

```
function offsetDate( date, hours ){
  return date.setUTCHours( date.getUTCHours() + hours );
}
```

**Edit**: You can choose to store a custom offset along with a date (as you can add custom properties to any JS object):

```
Date.prototype.withZone = function(){
  var o = new Date(this.getTime());                // Make a copy for mutating
  o.setUTCHours(o.getUTCHours() + (this.tz || 0)); // Move the UTC time

  // Return a custom formatted version of the date
  var offset = this.tz ? (this.tz<0 ? this.tz : ('+'+this.tz)) : 'Z';
  return o.customFormat('#YYYY#-#MMM#-#D# @ #h#:#mm##ampm# ('+offset+')');
}

// http://phrogz.net/JS/FormatDateTime_js.txt
Date.prototype.customFormat = function(formatString){
  var YYYY,YY,MMMM,MMM,MM,M,DDDD,DDD,DD,D,hhh,hh,h,mm,m,ss,s,ampm,AMPM,dMod,th;
  YY = ((YYYY=this.getUTCFullYear())+"").slice(-2);
  MM = (M=this.getUTCMonth()+1)<10?('0'+M):M;
  MMM = (MMMM=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"][M-1]).substring(0,3);
  DD = (D=this.getUTCDate())<10?('0'+D):D;
  DDD = (DDDD=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][this.getUTCDay()]).substring(0,3);
  th=(D>=10&&D<=20)?'th':((dMod=D%10)==1)?'st':(dMod==2)?'nd':(dMod==3)?'rd':'th';
  formatString = formatString.replace("#YYYY#",YYYY).replace("#YY#",YY).replace("#MMMM#",MMMM).replace("#MMM#",MMM).replace("#MM#",MM).replace("#M#",M).replace("#DDDD#",DDDD).replace("#DDD#",DDD).replace("#DD#",DD).replace("#D#",D).replace("#th#",th);
  h=(hhh=this.getUTCHours());
  if (h==0) h=24; if (h>12) h-=12;
  hh = h<10?('0'+h):h;
  AMPM=(ampm=hhh<12?'am':'pm').toUpperCase();
  mm=(m=this.getUTCMinutes())<10?('0'+m):m;
  ss=(s=this.getUTCSeconds())<10?('0'+s):s;
  return formatString.replace("#hhh#",hhh).replace("#hh#",hh).replace("#h#",h).replace("#mm#",mm).replace("#m#",m).replace("#ss#",ss).replace("#s#",s).replace("#ampm#",ampm).replace("#AMPM#",AMPM);
}

var now = new Date;            // Make a plain date
console.log( now.withZone() ); //-> 2012-Feb-16 @ 9:37pm (Z)
now.tz = -7;                   // Add a custom property for our method to use
console.log( now.withZone() ); //-> 2012-Feb-16 @ 2:37pm (-7)
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But I need not only display date in a specific time zone, I need to bind it to the UI control that allows to edit time component. The control accepts Date object and the user always has to see time in a specific time zone. I end up with converting Date object to the required time zone, so technically the date value becomes incorrect, since it displays time in one timezone, but the Date object internally keeps information about another timezone. Do you know any best practices to avoid such situation?

Comment: Good answer, may I suggest you add code to take Daylight Saving Time into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't set it, but u can get it: Here is a ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

```
var d = new Date()
var gmtHours = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
document.write("The local time zone is: GMT " + gmtHours);
```

Comment: Note: W3Schools is generally a very unreliable source of information. See http://w3fools.com for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers support toISOString(). Converting back to Date is not supported afaik.
You can find a working solution [here](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/07/ecmascript-iso-date-for-every-browser.html) for cross-browser support.